# 'cell' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a simple example through the python API of Spark:

```
x = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 1), ("a", 1)])
def f(x): return x
def add(a, b): return a + str(b)
sorted(x.combineByKey(str, add, add).collect())
```

There are no problems in the local mode (both Spark 1.0 and 1.1), but errors occur under the cluster mode. A piece of the problem traceback info is given as follows. Also it shows similar problems when testing the RDD function `cogroup()`. Its my first time to go through Spark's APIs (Python).

Do you have any idea?

```
[duplicate 561]
14/12/19 23:04:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Loss was due to org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.4-1.cdh5.1.4.p0.15/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 77, in main
serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.4-1.cdh5.1.4.p0.15/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1404, in pipeline_func
return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.4-1.cdh5.1.4.p0.15/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 283, in func
def func(s, iterator): return f(iterator)
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.4-1.cdh5.1.4.p0.15/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1118, in combineLocally
combiners = {}
AttributeError: 'cell' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: Isn't `a + str(b)` rather peculiar if `a` and `b` are both integers? Are you trying to add them as integers or concatenate them?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this?

Comment: @reokatoa This seems not a problem of Spark, but an integration issue from our Python distribution (we are using Anaconda Python). Problems disappeared when we switched to cluster's local python.